# Update additional_attributes for a product with catalogProductUpdate doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog, xml, soap

I am using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

With `catalogProductUpdate` (SOAP V2) all fields are updated but only my optional attribute with name `monitor2` does not updated with value `vijf`. I'd like to update my optional atrribute too.

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

[image: request XML catalogProductUpdate]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how the data is parsed before saving a product through the API.

```
    if (property_exists($productData, 'additional_attributes')) {
        if (property_exists($productData->additional_attributes, 'single_data')) {
            foreach ($productData->additional_attributes->single_data as $_attribute) {
                $_attrCode = $_attribute->key;
                $productData->$_attrCode = $_attribute->value;
            }
        }
        if (property_exists($productData->additional_attributes, 'multi_data')) {
            foreach ($productData->additional_attributes->multi_data as $_attribute) {
                $_attrCode = $_attribute->key;
                $productData->$_attrCode = $_attribute->value;
            }
        }
        unset($productData->additional_attributes);
    }
```

You can find this code in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2::_prepareDataForSave`.
notice the `single_data` and `multi_data` node in the product data.
Maybe you should format the request to include that node.
If something is still unclear this is a good place to start debugging.